# Почему я получаю ошибку "IndexError: list index out of range" и как ее исправить?

Tags: python, list, обработка-ошибок, индексация, python-faq

Цель создания данного вопроса и ответа к нему - обобщить всю информацию, относящуюся к ошибке:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

А также чтобы показать как определить почему и где в коде эта ошибка возникает и привести более-менее канонический ответ, чтобы ссылаться на него в будущем.

PS ответ планируется дополнять новыми примерами.

Comment: "Тут то мне карта и попёрла". Хорошая идея собрать типовые вопросы и грамотно разъяснить. :)  Есть похожий вопрос про ошибку с не числовым индексом, не знаю вот может имело бы смысл её в этом же вопросе тоже расписать, или нет.

Comment: @CrazyElf, мне кажется ошибку `"list indices must be integers or slices, not str"` - лучше описать подобным образом в отдельном вопросе-ответе. Возьметесь? ;)

Comment: Спасибо, но пока не могу - от работы голова пухнет. Думаю, потом ещё будут подходящие темы. Есть у меня издревле одна задумка по одному вопрос-ответу, надо будет как-нибудь реализовать потом. )

Comment: сюда хорошо подойдёт метка [python-faq]

Comment: @Danis, не знал о такой метке. Спасибо - добавил)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Суть этой ошибки очень проста - попытка обратиться к элементу списка/массива с несуществующим индексом.

Пример:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
print(lst[3])
```

вывод:

```
----> 2 print(lst[3])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Указанный в примере список имеет три элемента. Индексация в Python начинается с `0` и заканчивается `n-1`, где `n` - число элементов списка (AKA длина списка).
Соответственно для списка `lst` валидными индексами являются: `0`, `1` и `2`.

В Python также имеется возможность индексации **от конца** списка. В этом случае используются отрицательные индексы: `-1` - последний элемент, `-2` - второй с конца элемент, ..., `-n-1` - второй с начала, `-n` - первый с начала.

Т.е. если указать отрицательный индекс, значение которого превышает длину списка мы получим всё ту же ошибку:

```
In [2]: lst[-4]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ad46a138c96e> in <module>
----> 1 lst[-4]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

**В реальной жизни (коде)** эта ошибку чаще всего возникает в следующих ситуациях:

- если список пустой: `lst = []; first = lst[0]`
- в циклах - когда переменная итерирования (по индексам) дополнительно изменяется или когда используются глобальные переменные
- в циклах при использовании вложенных списков - когда перепутаны индексы строк и столбцов
- в циклах при использовании вложенных списков - когда размерности вложенных списков неодинаковые и код этого не учитывает. Пример: `data = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8]]` - если попытаться обратиться к элементу с индексом `2` во втором списке (`[4,5]`) мы получим `IndexError`
- в циклах - при изменении длины списка в момент итерирования по нему. Классический пример - попытка удаления элементов списка при итерировании по нему.

Поиск и устранения ошибки начинать нужно всегда с того, чтобы внимательно прочитать сообщение об ошибке (`error traceback`).

Пример скрипта (`test.py`), в котором переменная итерирования цикла `for <variable>`
изменяется (так делать нельзя):

```
lst = [1,2,3]
res = []

for i in range(len(lst)):
  i += 1   # <--- НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ переменную итерирования!
  res.append(lst[i] ** 2)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    res.append(lst[i] ** 2)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Обратите внимание что в сообщении об ошибке указан номер ошибочной строки кода - `File "test.py", line 6` и сама строка, вызвавшая ошибку:  `res.append(lst[i] ** 2)`. Опять же в реальном коде ошибка часто возникает в функциях, которые вызываются из других функций/модулей/классов. Python покажет в сообщении об ошибке весь стек вызовов - это здорово помогает при отладке кода в больших проектах.

После этого - мы точно знаем в каком месте кода возникает ошибка и можем добавить в код отладочную информацию, например напечатать значения индекса, который вызвал ошибку, понять почему используется неправильный индекс и исправить ошибку.

Comment: *"переменная итерирования цикла for <variable> изменяется (так делать нельзя)"* - а что не так то? Приведённый скрипт отработает без ошибок. Ибо сколько переменную цикла не меняй - на следующей итерации она всё-равно возьмёт следующее значение из range. Как раз с этим часто связана обратная ошибка - когда хотят пропустить индекс, модифицируют переменную цикла - а цикл всё-равно проходит по каждому элементу.

Comment: @GrAnd, спасибо, исправил пример

Comment: подскажите ее можно отловить только через try except?